# Nhibernate IList (ordered list) race condition

Tags: database, nhibernate, concurrency

Imagine this scenario:

1. An ordered collection on an entity.
2. Two simultaneous (asynchronous) CREATE requests for new items in the collection
3. Both new items get the same ordinal number.

The collection is like so:

```
public virtual IList<CustomField> CustomFields { get; protected set; }
```

I have the fluent nhibernate mapping like so:

```
mapping.HasManyToMany(cp => cp.CustomFields)
            .AsList(i => i.Column("CustomFieldOrdinal"))
            .ParentKeyColumn("RegistrationId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("CustomFieldId");
```

The reason being that nhibernate is querying the db to get the next available ordinal number and there is no lock on the table, and both are getting the same ordinal.

How can this be prevented?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your real use case? A problem like this could (should?) be handled on the database level, maybe changing the way you handle transactions in your create. Also, knowing the database you are using could be an information of use.

Comment: I'm using sql server (in azure). What else about my use case do you want to know. It's exactly as described. You think this is best handled at the db level? Currently I have it working...I'm using a table lock in the nhibernate transaction and it's working now.

Comment: You write "Both new items get the same ordinal number." But this is the effect. It's not the "how". How do you get NHibernate generate the ordinal number? The reason (and the possible solutions) of your problem is inside that point. "Using a table lock" is one way of solving it at the database level. Another is configuring the column with a default value, and have the db handle the calculation.

Comment: The how is the code in my post. The fluent nhibernate mapping and the property configuration.

Comment: Depending on the use case, you could make the CREATE request synchronized using a dedicated thread. This will still allow individual worker threads to process it asynchronously while waiting on each other. This synchronized behavior is what would happen using a LOCK on the database. Instead, you manage it explicitly in the code.

Comment: I'm not able to ascertain which approach your mappings are using to generate IDs. Using Fluent NHibernate, you can have the mapping capitalize on the AutoNumber feature of the database like so: `Id(x => x.ID).Column("ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();`. Seems like you'd need to have something like that in your mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with Nhibernate's `LockMode.Upgrade`. This works great and solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

An unique index/constraint in db would take care of that. Of course, you would then have to deal with a failed flush for one of the two requests.

If you want to avoid dealing with exception on application side, you may instead (or moreover) issue an exclusive db lock on the entity holding the list (`ISession.Lock(entity, LockMode.Upgrade)`) before reading (or refreshing from db) its list state. Then, update the list.
If all applications inserting to the list follow the same pattern, they will not be able to concurrently insert an element with the same index : they will wait for the lock to get freed, and will then have the new data in db before reading it and inserting their own new element.
This is a [pessimistic concurrency pattern](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/transactions.html#transactions-locking). Read more [here too](https://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency) (link found on this [other answer](/a/18362829/1178314)).

The optimistic one requires using a row-version column, and ensuring that any list update touch the entity version. But in case of concurrency, you would then have a concurrency exception for one of the two requests.

Comment: the ordinals aren't unique in the table because I can have 1-3 for one entity, and 1-3 for another entity. Also...users are allowed to reorder the collection...

Comment: The unique index/constraint should of course cover the entity id. As for the re-ordering, I hope NHibernate handles that by issuing its changes in an according way, but you should check that. (In my answer, I have change the `LockMode`, `Write` does not look as being the good one when checking documentation.)

Comment: Thinking about what I do in my real case uses, I do not use `list` mapping. I prefer using a mapped list item entity with an index property my application code handles itself, and have an [`order-by`](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-mapping) in the collection mapping, usually mapped as as `set`. This give me more control of how I handle the ordering, and it is more tolerant for inconsistent indexes.

Comment: So you just have an int ordinal property on your entity that you manage? In that case, how do you handle cases like this where you have two async requests?

Comment: I simply do not care (for my actual cases) : they will have the same index, and a sql order-by is tolerant to that (my application code too), it will still have some sound ordering. At the next update, it would be reordered.